# match a string in file java

Tags: java, string

I have a problem. I need to use the first row of the **txt** as my string and then look in the same **txt** the occurrences and print the number, but I have a problem, for example; if my **txt** is like: `wordwordword` and my string is word, it only counts the first word, it does´t print the counter: 3, print the counter: 1. How can I solve this?

### Demo.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c.txt"));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1;
        s1 = in.readLine();
        String Word;
        Word = s1;
        String line = in.readLine();
        int count = 0;
        String s[];
        do {
            s = line.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                String a = s[i];
                if (a.contains(Word))
                    count++;
            }
            line = in.readLine();
        } while (line != null);
        System.out.println("first line: " + s1);
        System.out.print("There are " + count + " occurences of " + Word
                + " in ");
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("c.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String word = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print(word);
        }
    }
}
```

**txt:**

> GAGCATAGA
>   CGAGAGCATATAGGAGCATATCTTGAGCATACCGAGCATATGAGCATAATATACCCGTCCGAGAGCATACACTGAGCATAAAGGAGCATAGAGCATACAACTGAGAATGGAGCATAGAGCATACGGAGCATAAGAGCATAGAGCATAGAGCATACGGAGCATAGAGCATAGAGCATAGCCGATGGGGAGCATACTGTTACGTAGAGCATACGAGCATAGCGCAAGAGCATAAAGAGCATAGAGCATATGAGCATATAGAGCATACGAGCATACAAGATCCGGGGAGCATAGCGAGGTAATAGTCGGAGCATAGAGCATAGAGCATATGAGCATACGGGAGCATAAATGAGCATAAGGAGCATAGAGCATAGAGCATAAGAGCATATCTCGAGCATAAGCGAGCATAGAGCATAAAAATCAATCACGTTGAGCATATGAGCATAAATACTGGAGCATAGATCGAGCATAGTAGAGCATACGAGCATAGAGCATAGGAGCATAAGAGCATATGAGCATATTGAGCATATGAAGGAGCATAAAAATGAGCATAAGGAGCATACCATCGTTGAGCATAATCCGAGCATAGGAGCATAGAATAGAGCATAGACAGGAGTTTTTGGAGCATATGAGCATAGAGCATAGAGCATAGAGCATAGAGCATAGAGCATAGAGCATATTCGAGCATAATTGAGCATATGAGCATAGAGCATATGGAGCATAGGCTGAGCATACCGAGCATAGCAATTAGAGCATAATCCTAGGGAGCATAGGAGCATACGTGAGCATAGCTGAGCATAGAGCATAGAGCATAGTGTTCGAGCATAGAGCATAGAGCATATGAGCATAGAGCATACTTGAGCATATGGTACGAGCATAGGAGCATATAAGGAGGAGCATATCGAGCATAGAGCATAGGCCTGGCCAGAGCATATAACCGAGCATAGGGTTGGAGCATAAGGCCGGAGCATACGAGCATACGAGCATATGAAATGAGCATAATGTGAGCATAGAGCATATCGAGCATATGAGCATAGGAGCATA

in this example with the txt, the program should print the counter= 21

Comment: post here what you have tried.

Comment: Please post the code in the question, not in comments. It's not particularly readable in comments.

Comment: Use the "edit" button below your question to add more details, such as your code.

Comment: Sorry I'm new, I will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Match {
public static String TEXT_FILE_LOCATION="input.txt";
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(TEXT_FILE_LOCATION));
    String stringToSearch=in.nextLine();
    StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
    for(;in.hasNext();){
        buffer.append(in.next());
    }
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(stringToSearch);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(buffer.toString());
    int from = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while(matcher.find(from)) {
        count++;
        from = matcher.start() + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Number of matches : "+count);
}
}
```

Comment: This code it was really useful, my problem was resolved, thank you.

Comment: Please don't just provide code. Explain what the code does and why it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by looping through your text then match the string with part of the text.

Here it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "word";
    String text = "wordwordword";
    int count = 0;
    for(int i =0 ; i <text.length() ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < word.length();j++){
            if((j+i)>=text.length())break;
            if(word.charAt(j)!=text.charAt(j+i))break;
            if(j==word.length()-1)count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);//prints 3
}
```

Also you could use `.toCharArray()` to get the characters in the string before looping to enhance the performance.

Here is the modified code for that :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] word = "word".toCharArray();
    char[] text = "wordwordword".toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    for(int i =0 ; i <text.length ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < word.length;j++){
            if((j+i)>=text.length)break;
            if(word[j]!=text[j+i])break;
            if(j==word.length-1)count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much useful :)

Comment: You are welcome :)
But take care for the definition of the problem , As this code gets you all occurrences that match the word even they are overlapped.